# Interfacing with the MLX91206

Tags: sensor, current, measurement

I am planning on using an [MLX91206](http://www.melexis.com/Hall-Effect-Sensor-ICs/Special-Purpose-Hall-ICs/MLX91206-755.aspx) to measure the current draw of a set of Peltier elements. They draw up to 17.3A at 24V.  However I would like to measure their current draw without interfering by placing sense resistors.
So I decided to use the MLX91206.  Could someone please explain how to connect this thing to an Arduino?  A rough pinout diagram would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet says

[image]

So I'd connect GND to GND, "Supply Voltage" to 5V and "Analog Output" to any free ADC input pin.

Comment: I was wondering about the PWM

Comment: @Jonny. I don't know about that but I'd look at [PulseIn](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/pulseIn) and find an [example](http://lordvon64.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/getting-pwm-frequency-and-duty-cycle.html)